# iFrame Busting On Manual Redirection (Logout Button) to a Page That Has iFrame Busting Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Okay, I know this is a very old question, and maybe already been answered on some discussion in here, but I can't find it till now, maybe I haven't search with the right keywords, but if any help about this frame busting problem or any link to the answer will be a great help, as my knowledge on JS and JQuery is really limited.

So here is the case, I was trying to make an affliates site with an iframe, but that site have iframe busting script `if (top!=self) {top.location = self.location;}`on the site index page called `Landing.aspx` and the logout page from what I inspet is at `/common/logout.aspx`, both of the page contain a same html code.

I can prevent the site from busting out the frame on the first time my site load that here is the, but after the user login on the affliate site inside the frame and then logout(that mean this is user input for manual redirection), the site will be broke out of the frame, and the site url will change to `http://example.com/Landing.aspx?type=logout` why the "prevent frame busting script" not function when user click on logout at the affliate site inside the frame.

Note: the affliate site is running on flash, so i cannot use the iframe sandbox, because it prevent the flash running and make the user cannot login to the site.

So how can I make when the user click on logout, when the logout page load it will still contained inside the iframe or can i make it to shoot back to my own url

here is my `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  <some other meta.../>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="hidejs.js" ></script>
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {

   });
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="header">
    header content
  </div>

  <div class="wrap">
    //iframe created should be placed here
  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    footer content
  </div>
 <body>
</html>
```

and here is the content of `hidejs.js` this script i found in one of the discussion here about hiding code from viewsource and inspect element. and the reason i use javascript to create the iframe because if i write the iframe on `index.html` the source site will breaking out of the frame before the prevent iframe bust script can hold it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var ga = document.createElement('script');
     ga.type = 'text/javascript';
     ga.src = 'hiding.js';
     ga.id = 'hiding';
     document.querySelector("head").appendChild(ga);
$('#hiding').remove();

var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.id = 'fram';
    iframe.name = 'fram';
    iframe.src = 'http://www.example.com';
    iframe.style.height = 'someheight';
    iframe.style.width = 'somewidth';
    iframe.scrolling = 'no';
    iframe.frameBorder = '0';
    document.querySelector("body > div.wrap").appendChild(iframe);
});
```

so this `hidejs.js` will create and link to javascript file called `hiding.js` inside head tag and iframe inside  div inside body tag, and the script inside this `hiding.js` is the iframe buster busting script that i also found in here too

```
var prevent_bust = 0
window.onbeforeunload = function() { prevent_bust++ }
setInterval(function() {
   if (prevent_bust > 0) {
       prevent_bust -= 2
       window.top.location = 'index.html#fram'
   }
}, 1)
```

Really need help on this case.